# is there a way to automate xx:05 as the meeting start and xx:55 as the meeting end by default in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, calendar, meetings

Is there a registry edit trick or a macro I can use to have the default timings of my meetings start 5 minutes after full hour and end 5 minutes prior full hour. I do this by hand right now to remove the problem of someone being late to the meeting - I start at "5 minutes past" sharp ... this works well but is a nightmare to click through when scheduling a meeting.

Answer (score 5):

I have googled for solution finally - its not a thing that comes visible with a simple search though. Seems not many people interested.

I am writing from a PC where I do not have Outlook installed, but hope I remember that well.

1. You need to enable Developer "ribbon" in Outlook
2. You need to create new form (using Appointment Form as a base)
3. On this new form - you need to put a VBA code for Open action
4. in this code - you need to modify Item. Start and Item. End (only if its set to full hour or half an hour, if you miss this piece your appointment will "shrink" each time you open it. Start should be +5 minutes, end should be -10 minutes (as the +5 for start actually pushes End 5 minutes forward as well).
5. While you are at editing new form you may want to add some standard footer in the invite (e. G. your conference call number).
6. Save this form ("Publish Form As... " if I remember this well)
7. Right click in the calendar view on your Calendar "folder" and change default form to be used from Appointment to the one you have saved in point 6.

Hope you will be able to follow this with a little help of google. The solution is to

1. create new form
2. add small VBA at its beginning
3. select this form as your new default "Calendar form".

Comment: Could you a link to a file where you have put the code for others to copy.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Outlook has this feature in later versions: https://chrismenardtraining.com/post/outlook-buffer-time

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guideline:

https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-methods-change-default-duration-appointment-meeting-outlook/

and use the following macro instead:

```
Private WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Private WithEvents objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInspectors = Outlook.Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is AppointmentItem Then
       Set objAppointment = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub objAppointment_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Set the default duration of new appointment
    If objAppointment.CreationTime = #1/1/4501# Then
       objAppointment.Duration = "50"
       objAppointment.Start = DateAdd("n", 5, objAppointment.Start)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub objAppointment_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
    'When you disable the "All Day Event"
    'Change the default duration of the current appointment
    If Name = "AllDayEvent" Then
       If objAppointment.AllDayEvent = False Then
          objAppointment.Duration = "50"
          objAppointment.Start = DateAdd("n", 5, objAppointment.Start)
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```